# Confusion regarding detailed working of compilation and execution stage in .net framework

Tags: .net, assembly, compilation, manifest, execution

I am learning .net framework theoretical concepts(using wiki and google). As I understand from this [this image on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CLR_diag.svg), the primary(and most basic) view of the compilation and execution process in the .net framework says that the various source codes in c#, j#, vb.net, etc. are COMPILED into a platform-neutral bytecode called CLI code(common intermediate language code), which is then COMPILED(or is it INTERPRETED?) into a platform-dependent code called native code. This code is created in a way that provides nonproblematic and easy execution on the specific platform. But I got confused regarding the detailed description of the source code to bytecode compilation stage as given over [here](http://www.scriptol.com/programming/cil.php). My questions are:

1. Why is the CIL code being stored in this assembly, PE format and manifest?
2. What are they?
3. Why not directly convert it into native executable code. Also, it is mentioned that the CIL code is compiled either 1) to a bytecode (which is interpreted to executable code). or 2) to a binary executable code.
4. Can you give example of some platforms where .net applies these 2 techniques individually? Please explain it in simple terms.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whether the code is compiled or interpreted into platform-dependent code is just an implementation detail. However, with the 'normal' .NET framework this code is compiled to machine code (for obvious performance reasons). With the micro .NET framework (for embedded devices) the IL is interpreted, not compiled (main reason is to keep memory usage down).

Comment: @Steven Thankyou. That cleared one thing !!!

Comment: If it's homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky No, it is not homework. I am an entry level programmer and am learning it from home.

Answer (score 0):

PE Format is the structure for exe and dlls.
It was originally designed for stuff in native code.
Reusing it meant they didn't have to rewrite windows, instead the put a ".net flag" in the file and if it's set the OS tells the the ,net run time to "run it" From the front end (as in you double clicking an icon in your desktop the change is transparent.

You detailed the mission statement reason for IL, yourself, if you want to havea look at what it really means, have a look at the mono project.

IL is not interpreted, there are simply two compile stages one to IL (if you want you can write raw IL).  Then one from IL to native. The advantages are many, but an easy ione to see is how many .net languages there are. They all get comiled .IL, and then there is one IL to native for each target architecture (32 / 64 bit for instance). So if you had say six .net languages and four OS/Architectures that's ten programs to write and maintain, without IL it's effectively 24...

The .net run time does what is called JIT compiling. The first tiem you refer to say your Car class in your car assembly it compiles Car to native code and then uses it from then on. If you run up the app and only look at bikes, car doesn't get compiled. That's great but compilation can take time, in some instances too much, so there is a tool called NGEN which just compiles the lot. You do that as part of the install, no more JIT cost.

The link you provided about be interpreted to a JIT is tad misleading in my opinion. There's certainly no reason why you couldn't have an IL interpreter, but that isn't waht the framework does. JustInTime compilation, is what usually happens. Waht you can do however is use a tool called NGEN which does a full compile of teh exe / dll, taking JIT out of the equation. Not often but is possible for the inherrent delay in JIT to be an issue. NGEN basically manually compiles everything in advance so your app doesn't have to be delayed by compilation.